# Can I count dates grouped by year?

Tags: r

I've got some data that looks about like so:

```
demo <- read.table(text = "
date             num
'12/31/2010'     35
'04/01/2013'     34
'06/02/2015'     34
'06/15/2015'     34
'01/30/2015'     33
'04/15/2014'     33
'05/28/2014'     33
'06/02/2014'     33
'06/17/2015'     33
'06/25/2015'     33
'06/24/2015'     32
'07/31/2013'     32
'08/31/2013'     32
'04/27/2015'     31
'05/07/2015'     31
'12/30/2013'     31
'11/21/2014'     30
'12/20/2013'     30
",header = TRUE, sep = "")
```

How do I group and count these by year?

```
2010   1
2013   5
```

etc.

I can use `plyr` to count each date: `count(demo, vars = 'date')`, but not group them.

Comment: four digits after a `/` at the end of the string `table(gsub('.*/(\\d{4})$', '\\1', demo$date))`

Comment: Lots of great options here. I opted to go with `lubridate` just on principle.

Comment: loading a package, creating another dependency, another opportunity for breaking code, masking functions, just to do one task. ugh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd convert the dates to a date format first, rather than treating them as strings.

```
library(lubridate)
# Convert string to date format
demo$date <- as.Date(demo$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
# Table of counts by year
table(year(demo$date))

# 2010 2013 2014 2015 
#   1    5    4    8
```

Answer (score 3):

I like *data.table* for this.  First we need to convert to "Date" class in the `date` column, then find the number of observations by year.

```
library(data.table)

demo$date <- as.Date(demo$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
as.data.table(demo)[, .N, keyby = year(date)]
#    year N
# 1: 2010 1
# 2: 2013 5
# 3: 2014 4
# 4: 2015 8
```

We use `keyby` here so we get a nice ordered result.  Alternatively, and to change your entire table to a data.table, you can use `setDT()` instead of `as.data.table()`. This is the preferred method.

```
setDT(demo)[, .N, keyby = year(date)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table(substr(demo$date, 7,10))

2010 2013 2014 2015 
   1    5    4    8
```

`substr` allows you isolate the year, and `table` tallies the amounts.

Answer (score 1):

```
demo$date <- as.Date(demo$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
demo$year <- format(demo$date, format = "%Y")
aggregate(num ~ year, demo, FUN = length)
##   year num
## 1 2010   1
## 2 2013   5
## 3 2014   4
## 4 2015   8
```

Answer (score 1):

Date formats can be modified using Date and POSIXct classes. This allows you to handle dates that looks like '1/1/2010'.

```
dates <- as.Date(demo$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
head(dates)
# [1] "2010-12-31" "2013-04-01" "2015-06-02" "2015-06-15" "2015-01-30"
# [6] "2014-04-15"

table(format(dates, format = "%Y"))
#
# 2010 2013 2014 2015 
#    1    5    4    8
```