# Can I cross tab dates, grouped by year?

Tags: r, aggregate

I cleared one hurdle, with [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150756/can-i-count-dates-grouped-by-year) from SO and thought the next hurdle would be easier. What I *really* have is start *and* end dates in a data frame:

```
require(lubridate)

demo <- read.table(text = "
start   end num
2010-12-31        <NA>  35
2013-04-01        <NA>  34
2015-06-02        <NA>  34
2015-06-15  2012-12-31  34
2015-01-30  2011-12-31  33
2014-04-15  2013-12-31  33
2014-05-28  2013-12-31  33
2014-06-02        <NA>  33
2015-06-17        <NA>  33
2015-06-25        <NA>  33
2015-06-24        <NA>  32
2013-07-31        <NA>  32
2013-08-31        <NA>  32
2015-04-27        <NA>  31
2015-05-07        <NA>  31
2013-12-30        <NA>  31
2014-11-21        <NA>  30
2013-12-20  2013-06-30  30
",header = TRUE, sep = "")

demo$start <- as.Date(demo$start, '%Y-%m-%d')
demo$end <- as.Date(demo$end, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I can get a table of start years, or a table of end years, with `table(year(demo$end))` or `table(year(demo$start))` which is a lovely start. But what I really want to know is something more like: for each year, how many entries that started have not yet ended? So count `is.na()` for each start year.

I thought I could use `aggregate()` for that, but this:

```
aggregate(is.na(end) ~ year(start), demo, FUN = length)
```

But that seems to be counting every observation, not just the observations for which the end date `is.na()`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the number of NA values for each 'year', we can use `sum` as the `is.na(end)` is a logical vector.  The `length` gives the total length of the vector per `year` instead of the `length` of the `TRUE` values

```
aggregate(cbind(end=is.na(end)) ~ cbind(year=year(start)), demo, FUN = sum)
#  year end
#1 2010   1
#2 2013   4
#3 2014   2
#4 2015   6
```

---

Or we can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(demo)`), grouped by the `year` of the 'start' column and using `i` as `is.na(end)` as row index, we get the `.N` or the number of elements for each group.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(demo)[is.na(end), list(end = .N) , list(year=year(start))]
#   year end
#1: 2010   1
#2: 2013   4
#3: 2015   6
#4: 2014   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use table with multiple arguments to give you 2-way or multi-way tables:

```
> with(demo, table( year=format(demo$start, "%Y"), Not.missing = !is.na(end) ) )
      Not.missing
year   FALSE TRUE
  2010     1    0
  2013     4    1
  2014     2    2
  2015     6    2
```

You could also use `lubridate::year` instead of hte format call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
demo %>% subset(is.na(end)) %>% group_by(year(start)) %>% summarise(n=length(end))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#
#  year(start) n
#1        2010 1
#2        2013 4
#3        2014 2
#4        2015 6
```

This is pretty straightforward. With your original data (demo), `subset` to only get the `NA` in your `end` column. Afterwards (and using `year()` from the `lubridate` package), group by each `year`, and get the summary of the number of `NAs` present in the `end` column. This will return a `data.frame` object.